# The effect of Decision Tree Pruning

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, data-mining, decision-tree

I want to know if I build up a decision tree A like ID3 from training and validation set,but A is unpruned.
At the same time,I have another decision tree B also in ID3 generated from the same training and validation set,but B is pruned.
Now I test both A and B on a future unlabeled test set,is it always the case that pruned tree will perform better?
Any idea is welcomed,thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for specific cases where the pruned tree could perform worse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we need to make the distinction clearer: pruned trees always perform better on the **validation** set, but not necessarily so on the **testing** set (in fact it is also of equal or worse performance on the **training** set). I am assuming that the pruning is done after the tree is built (ie: post-pruning)..

Remember that the whole reason of using a validation set is to avoid *overfitting* over the training dataset, and the key point here is *generalization*: we want a model (decision tree) that generalizes beyond the instances that have been provided at "training time" to new unseen examples.

Answer (score 1):

Pruning is *supposed* to improve classification by preventing overfitting. Since pruning will only occur if it improves classification rates on the validation set, a pruned tree will perform as well or better than an un-pruned tree during validation.

Comment: the OP never mentioned cross-validation, I think you meant validation set

Comment: @Amro: Right, on the validation set during cross-validation. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Bad pruning can lead to wrong results. Although a reduced decision tree size is often desired, you usually aim for better results when pruning. Therefore the *how* is the crux of the pruning.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with 1st answer by @AMRO. `Post-pruning` is the most common approach for decision tree pruning and it is done after the tree is built. But, `Pre-pruning` can also be done. in `pre-pruning`, a tree is pruned by halting its construction early, by using a specified threshold value. For example, by deciding not to split the subset of training tuples at a given node.

Then that node becomes a leaf. This leaf may hold the most frequent class among the subset of tuples or the probability of those tuples.